# Comparing two exponentiations

Tags: exponentiation

$b^n$ where the base $b$ is a positive integer greater than $1$ and the exponent $n$ is a rational number in simplified form.  How would one compare (resulting in <, =, or >) two such exponentiations without evaluating the exponentiatoins, and without the use of functions or operations that produce real numbers (e.g., log(), pow(), etc)?

Comment: As in comparing $b^n$ and $c^m$ ? different bases and different exponents?

Comment: I do not understand what is being asked.  Could you please elaborate?  What do you mean by compare?

Comment: if $gcd(b,c)=1$ can the two numbers be equal?

Comment: I give an algorithm for exactly this problem in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97049/comparing-powers-without-logarithms

Comment: @RustynYazdanpour I don't know.

Answer (score 3):

In order to compare, say, $b_{1}^{p_{1}/q_{1}}$ and $b_2^{p_2/q_2}$, the simplest approach is to raise both to the same power ($q_1 q_2$) and compare the resulting integers, $b_{1}^{p_1 q_2}$ and $b_2^{p_2 q_1}$.

Comment: That won't work for all cases because the exponents can be negative rationals.  Besides, I forgot to mention in my question, I can't evaluate the exponentiation because it can easily overflow.

Comment: If both exponents are negative, do the comparison with positive exponents and return the opposite result.  If one is negative and the other non-negative, then the one with the negative exponent is smaller.  And you need, I think, to be able to use either big integers or floating-point numbers to do this problem.